# external table cannot run inside transaction block

Tags: python, list, dictionary

trying to understand this error and possibly what can be done to fix it. Any help or ideas on how I could improve the logic would be greatly recommended. The error I receive says alter external table cannot run inside a transaction block.

```
 print(partition)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("alter table table_name add partition(partitionid = 
'" + (str(partition)) + "') LOCATION 's3://bucketname/folder/folder/'")
 cur.close()

 partition = infile.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error relates to transaction isolation level.

By setting `autocommit` to `True`, the query won't execute as a transaction, and you would be able to add your partition to the external table:

```
con.autocommit = True
cur = con.cursor()
```